# How to display a text as bold in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a datagrid in window application c#.net.
I want to display a text as bold dynamically.

Using the below code i am getting the error font.bold is only read only.

```
Datagrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

Is there anyother way displaying a text dynamically in a datagrid ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var myBoldFont = new Font(myBaseFont, FontStyle.Bold);
Datagrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font = myBoldFont;
```

Comment: Hi wat is myBaseFont here ? how can i create it ?